# How can I "remove" the embed segue in my container view, or remove the container view completely?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `splashViewController` with a `containerView`, which is created in Storyboard.

In my story board, I automatically drag an embed segue from my `containerView` to a `profileViewController`.

Inside my `splashViewController`, I want to programatically "destroy" the `containerView` + `profileViewController`(both of them).

I've tried this:

```
self.containerView.hidden = true //obviously doesn't work. it's just visual
self.containerView.removeFromSuperView() //nope. it's just visual.
```

How can I remove both containerView **and** profileViewController completely, making sure that both `deinit` appropriately?  If that's not possible, can I at least deinit the profileViewController? (I'll just set containerView as hidden).

Note: I play a movie video automatically (looping) in my profileViewController. It has sound, and even when I set containerView to nil and remove it from superview, the sound keeps playing.

Comment: what causes that sound? How do you allocate it?

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to the view controller anywhere?

Comment: The sound is caused by the MPMoviePlayerController inside profile. I play video automatically, and as far as I know, MPMoviePlayerController does not allow you to mute the sound.

Comment: Why do you care about when they get destroyed?  I see references to sounds in comments, but nothing in the question.  Has some context been edited out? `self.containerView.removeFromSuperView(); self.containerView = nil` should free your references to the view, but without more context, who know who else may hold a reference to the view(s).

Comment: @JonBrooks I've editted my question.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is a singleton AND deprecated in iOS 9.  The audio keeps playing because it is designed to be accessible outside your app (like when doing AirPlay).  You'll need to manually stop it using [instance stop] on viewDidDisappear or the like, as far as I have experimented with it.  In any case, probably worth moving away from it after its deprecation.

Comment: @diatrevolo what takes its place?

Comment: @TIMEX I'd probably go with AVPlayer and its family, although it seems MPMoviePlayerViewController (as opposed to MPMoviePlayerController) gets a stay of execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote up a quick example project here demonstrating the solution [here](https://github.com/kevinrandrup/Test_Movie).
An autoplaying video (with dog barking) automatically plays in the bottom of the screen. Pressing the "Stop Player" button removes the child `UIViewController` and the container.

`MPMoviePlayerController` finished playing the audio even after the moviePlayer was stopped or set to nil (although not necessarily deallocated if an internal part of the `MPMoviePlayerController` held a strong reference which I suspect was the problem).

Anyway, I found a workaround by setting the `contentURL` of the movie player to nil on `deinit` before calling `moviePlayer.stop()`

```
//The `ProfileViewController` is created in the storyboard as a child of `ViewController`. 
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView?

    @IBAction func stopPlayer(sender: UIButton) {            
        //We remove the child view controller (the ProfileViewController) from the parent
        for controller in self.childViewControllers {
            if let child = controller as? ProfileViewController {
                child.removeFromParentViewController() //This causes the deinit call
                container?.removeFromSuperview() //Clear up the container (stays as a black box otherwise)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `ProfileViewController`, we have to change the contentURL and stop our movie player

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController = {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TestMovie", ofType: "mp4")!
        let moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)!)
        moviePlayer.movieSourceType = .File
        moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame
        return moviePlayer
    }()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
        moviePlayer.play()

        //Looping
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "moviePlayerDidFinish:", name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: moviePlayer)
    }

    //Change our contentURL then stop
    deinit {
        moviePlayer.contentURL = nil
        moviePlayer.stop()
    }

    @objc func moviePlayerDidFinish(notification: NSNotification) {
        let reasonInt = notification.userInfo![MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] as! Int
        let reason = MPMovieFinishReason(rawValue: reasonInt)
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReason.PlaybackEnded) {
            moviePlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on a iPhone 5 device and on the simulator

### tl;dr

1. Remove the container `UIView` itself by calling `removeFromSuperview`
2. The `MPMoviePlayerController` keeps playing audio after being stopped, this is a bug. Workaround it by setting the contentURL then stopping

Answer (score 1):

There are some details missing here, so I'll try to do my best, but it sounds like containerView is not the main view of that UIViewController, as I don't think you can say self.view.removeFromSuperView()

If you want to have a pattern where you delete the container view, I would recommend taking a look at how Apple suggests that you do this with their [ContainerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)  There are a few more steps involved but it allows you to easily add and remove children.  The downside is that you need to have a ViewController associated with each view.

The issue that it sounds like you are dealing with is this MPMoviePlayerController.  MPMoviePlayerController requires a view associated with it.  From Apple's documentation

> Playback occurs in a view owned by the movie player and takes place
>   either fullscreen or inline. You can incorporate a movie player’s view
>   into a view hierarchy owned by your app, or use an
>   MPMoviePlayerViewController object to manage the presentation for you.

My guess would be without looking at any code, that MPMoviePlayerController is hanging onto a reference to one of the view's that your deleting and its a strong reference so it isn't letting you actually delete that view and causing it to continue without being on screen.

It looks like MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated in ios9 so you should move to [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer), which should give you more control over a movie inside your view

Answer (score -1):

I think you should find a way to stop playing sounds. Also, you can just assign `nil` to those view controllers you want to deallocate. However, you can not do `self = nil;`.

Comment: setting them to nil won't deinit them necessarily :) -- that only works if you own the last reference to the item (just saying for clarification benefits)

Comment: Under ARC, you can not explicitly can dealloc. That's why you need to de-reference it so that the system will clean this for you when necessary.

Comment: Thanks ;) but nilling has no immediate effect if someone else retains it. Thats under arc.

Comment: Yes. That's why you need to clear it up so that the iOS will clean it up in the future

Comment: Nevermind. I was just enforcing that nilling isn't freeing anything. :)